# Python - start HTTP server AND set windows system tray

Tags: python, multithreading, blocking

I have a python script which starts a basic web server and responds to certain input, that works fine. I also have the windows system tray icon working (shows an ico file) - but at the moment the script seems to block at the point of showing the system icon.

I would just like to have a python HTTP server listening, and a system tray icon showing while the script is running - this is already a hidden python window and I'd like to know if it fails for any reason.

Do I need to start two separate threads? or is there a better way to do this? here was my original code (excerpt only):

```
hover_text = "My Tray Icon Text"
def hello(sysTrayIcon): print "Hello World."
def simon(sysTrayIcon): print "Hello Simon."
def switch_icon(sysTrayIcon):
    pass
menu_options = (('Say Hello', None, hello),
                ('Switch Icon', None, switch_icon),
                ('A sub-menu', None, (('Say Hello to Simon', None, simon),
                                              ('Switch Icon', None, switch_icon),
                                             ))
               )
def bye(sysTrayIcon):
    print ("Server stopped by user")
    sys.exit()
    # server.shutdown()

print("setting system tray icon")
SysTrayIcon("hazard.ico", hover_text, menu_options, on_quit=bye, default_menu_index=1)

print("starting server")


#local only
#server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 9006), GetHandler)

#listen on all interfaces
server = HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 9006), GetHandler)

#print 'Starting server, use  to stop'
server.serve_forever()
```

I tried moving the server start before the system tray icon setting like this:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target = server.serve_forever())
```

but it then blocks at the server start piece, no icon is set.

I also tried this

```
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn

class ThreadingServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    pass

srvr = ThreadingServer(('0.0.0.0', 9006), GetHandler)
srvr.serve_forever()
```

[reference](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0420__Network/BasicHTTPServerExamplewiththreading.htm) 
but it still blocks at the server piece.

Should I maybe be using multiprocessing rather than multi-threading ? the script is reasonably small & trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `SysTrayIcon()` call is blocking (not familiar with this function and the providing module is missing from the code sample).

If so, then one solution is to start the server in a separate thread, as you tried.
One thing to note is that when a thread is starting, a **reference** to the function should be passed for the `target` of the `Thread()`.

So the code you'll need is like:

```
server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
server_thread.start()
```

Instead of **calling** the method. In the code sample, the `server.serve_forever` is being called, hence the block (that method blocks accepting and handling HTTP requests, forever).

Even if you chose the `ThreadingMixIn` from the `SocketServer`, the call to `serve_forever` should be done in a separate thread. The `ThreadingMixIn` allows the server to serve each HTTP request in a different thread, but the call to `serve_forever` will still block the current thread.

Also I'd suggest thinking about a proper way to stop the server thread (using `threading.Event` for example) when your app is going to stop. Or maybe it's simple to call the `SysTrayIcon()` in another thread:

```
threading.Thread(target=SysTrayIcon, args=("hazard.ico", hover_text, menu_options), kwargs=dict(on_quit=bye, default_menu_index=1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apologies, here's a reference link for the tray icon code : http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/SysTrayIcon.py.html 

I already use a reference to the function but it's still blocking on myThread1.start()
I will continue to play around with this and see what I can get done.

and yes don't worry the sys,exit was a placeholder only. ;-)

Comment: I tried your second edit also , the calling systray icon in another thread. they BOTH block for some reason. I've a feeling I'm going about this all wrong, but will figure it out soon

Comment: I don't have experience with Python Win32 API, some GUI frameworks require using the main thread for some operations. You may find such tricks. In general if you detect blocking calls and start them in threads, the main thread won't block (unless a thread is a busy loop, which starves other threads from being processed properly).

Comment: The `SocketServer` module is OK to work with threads (or even multiprocessing), so it won't block your main thread if you start the server in another thread. But you'll have to work a bit to stop the server thread gracefully. It's not difficult, but needs attention.